# Find a code to detect YouTube video end and hide related video on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, youtube, code-snippets

I'm looking for a little help about creating a code snippet for Wordpress to auto detect when embed YouTube video ends and hide related video.

I found a code example on the Internet but was for a single video. Would be nice to be able to find a code that can work on Wordpress standard embed video and can detect the end of the video using YouTube API then just hide related video and show again the initial image of the video when the video ends.

I use the Wordpress gutemberg classic editor to embed videos. If i look at the article source code...

`<iframe width="853" height="450" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Sft-fasbVnY" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>`

I have a page where there are a lot of videos that are showed on more pages.
I cannot customize the embed code for every video, I'm looking for a snipped code that can work for all videos like a plugin that never need to insert any code or meta tag to any existent videos.

Comment: I'm still searching a working code. I hope some one can add a reply soon or later that will help me :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think the below can be useful:

```
function add_youtube_end_detect_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        var playerElements = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src*="youtube.com/embed"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < playerElements.length; i++) {
            var player = new YT.Player(playerElements[i], {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': function(event) {
                        if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                            event.target.classList.add('video-ended');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    var styles = document.createElement('style');
    styles.innerHTML = '.video-ended { pointer-events: none; }';
    document.head.appendChild(styles);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_youtube_end_detect_script');
```

Add this code to the "functions.php" file of your WordPress theme

Comment: Done, I also cleared cache but is not working.

Comment: okay let me propose you something else

Comment: Sure, you can test also the code here: https://htmledit.squarefree.com
Will be awersome be able to resolve the related video showed by YouTube for all wordpress embed videos :-) Thanks for the help

Answer (score -2):

Try this one :

```
function add_youtube_end_detect_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        var players = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src*="youtube.com/embed"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            var player = new YT.Player(players[i], {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': function(event) {
                        if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                            var container = event.target.getIframe().parentNode;
                            container.classList.add('video-ended');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    var styles = document.createElement('style');
    styles.innerHTML = '.video-ended .ytp-pause-overlay { display: none !important; }';
    document.head.appendChild(styles);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_youtube_end_detect_script');
```

Comment: Still not work. You can also try to paste this script in a html real time editor and embed a video. Seems the script is not able to detect the video so nothing happen at the end.